# Check all data keys in golang at once

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
type DisplayObject struct {
    ID      string `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"id"`
    URI     string `json:"uri,omitempty" bson:"uri"`
    Display string `json:"display,omitempty" bson:"display"`
}

if DisplayObject.ID != "" {
    // do something
}

if DisplayObject.URI != "" {
    // do something
}

if DisplayObject.Display != "" {
    // do something
}
```

In javascript I would do

```
for (var key in DisplayObject) {
  if (DisplayObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

How can I accomplish this for loop through an object in go?

Comment: Either with reflection or as you did which looks fine to me.

Comment: Are you trying to check whether there is at least one non-empty field within the structure? Or do you actually want to find _every_ non-empty field in there and somehow react on its name/value? (although a comment, the `pass the data` bit in your code is confusing for me)

Comment: Yeah that data comment was out of context i suppose. My apologies, updated it to be less confusing. But yes, I would like to loop through every field, empty or not, and handle it. It looks as though that can't be done in go. Which is ok, I just wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reflection to accomplish something like that:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type DisplayObject struct {
    ID      string `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"id"`
    URI     string `json:"uri,omitempty" bson:"uri"`
    Display string `json:"display,omitempty" bson:"display"`
}

func main() {
    displayObj := &DisplayObject{ID: "foo"}
    s := reflect.ValueOf(displayObj).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldName := s.Type().Field(i).Name
        fieldValue := s.Field(i).String()
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", fieldName, fieldValue)
        // do something with the field data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying compare uncomparable. Javascript object is similar to map[string]interface{} . In your case could also be map[string]string and for maps you can use len(m) == 0.

Struct is much faster container, but less flexible container. You cannot change number or types of members.

Comment: @thatgibbyguy, to expand on this answer: JS, being a dynamic typeless language, has the concepts of "objects" and "maps" (dictionaries, hashes) pretty much blended. Go, being a compiled language with static typing, has these concepts rather distinct: `struct`s can't be queried for their fields at runtime (except for the long and slow path through the `reflect` package) but you can use `.FieldName` notation to access the fields of the objects of `struct` types. And you can't add or remove fields to such objects at runtime.

Comment: @thatgibbyguy, on the other hand, you are able to add and remove values to Go `map`s but you can't use `.KeyName` notation to access these values -- only the `map[KeyName]` notation.  And you are able to iterate over all the key/value pairs in a map at runtime.

Comment: @thatgibbyguy, what this means, in the end, is that you should take your pick: either use struct and write the code which checks the invariant or deserialize your data to a map and then use a (possibly simpler) code to check your invariant. But please think your solution through -- don't buy on this on-the-spot simplicity; try overseeing a bigger picture instead.

Comment: @kostix thanks. yes this is a radical departure from my normal way of coding, and being that Go's biggest strength to me is its use of types and that it's compiled. As such, I should just bite the bullet and be as explicit as possible. Thanks for all your help and insight.